# How to use logical OR in Cypress should assertion

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress, assert

I have this code

```
cy.get(element).should('contain.text', search_word || search_word.toLowerCase())
```

And I get this error

```
expected <div.games__element__title.card-title.h5> to contain text Hot, but the text was Ultimate hot
```

How can I use OR operator, so I can assert that the text of element contains the searching word written either in uppercase or in lowercase letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For text comparison, instead of using OR approach, I suggest using lowercase comparison by having the expected text and actual text to be compared in the lowercase version. This is a cleaner approach.

```js
cy.get(element).invoke('text').should(text => {
  expect(text.toLowerCase()).to.contain(search_word.toLowerCase());
})
```

another alternative is using regex

```js
cy.get(element).invoke('text').should('match', /(h|H)ot/);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve what you are looking for, is by using the Conditional statement in cypress. We will get the inner Text from the element and then check whether the word **hot** or **Hot** is present in the text and based on that we will perform actions.

```
cy.get(element).invoke('text').then((text) => {
   if (text.includes('Hot')) {
      //Do Something
   }
   else if (text.includes('hot')) {
      //Do Something
   }
   else {
      //Do Something
   }
})
```

Comment: Yes, this would solve my problem, but it is not fact that the element contains the text. The target is to assert that the element contains the text. It may not contain hot also

Comment: What I understood is that the element will give you the text `Ultimate hot` now you want to validate that whether the second word is either `hot `or `Hot` or is it something else ?

Comment: The element can give me only **Ultimate** or **Ultimate hot** or **Ultimate Hot**. If the element doesn't give me the word **hot** or **Hot**, the test should fail.

Comment: There is also the concept of **conditional testing** mentioned in cypress documentation - similar to this answer: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing. The difference is that, in the guide, `.then` is followed by another `.then` statement reacting to the result found by the first `.then`.